# Force logout on web application

Tags: html, asp.net, logout

I currently have a logout button on a web application which abandons the session and then redirects the user to a login page. The only problem is there are other processes running that the button is waiting for before completing the logout.

Is there any way to force the logout regardless of other processes?

Comment: What are these other processes? can these not be signalled in some way to abort/finish gracefully?

Answer (score 0):

System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear()

Session.Clear();

FormsAuthentication.SignOut();

Response.Cache.SetNoStore();